# Should I ask Pong questions here or on SO?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

Since Pong is a tag at main site SO and not a tag on gamedev, is the preferred place to ask about Pong on SO even if Pong is game development? I saw that Pong runs on some FPGA and asked about it it but I think it got too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pong as in the game pong?  There probably isn't a tag for it because nobody has asked any questions about it.

As far as progrmaming questions go, see the faq.  If a game developer will likely give you a better answer than the audience of SO, feel free to ask it here.  Most game developers probably don't deal with a lot of embedded hardware, or whatever FGPAs are classified as.

Comment: Yes as in the game Pong. There're no games AFAIK for the Nios II CPU, I [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872409/how-to-make-pong-for-the-nios-ii-processors) and removed the question since it's probably very uninteresting if you don't have this FPGA (Altera DE2). I asked and got no reply.